# Update a CRM 2011 record using LINQ example

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

Can someone please post a **confirmed** example using linq to retrieve and update a record in CRM Dynamics 2011.

Microsoft claims this is "unsupported" but I have a suspicion it is possible.

Comment: Can you please refer to the source of your assertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rough example of using the ODATA provider connected to the online provider

```
             var serverConfig = GetServerConfig(sessionKey);
            // Connect to the Organization service. 
            // The using statement ensures that the service proxy will be properly disposed.

            using (var serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serverConfig.OrganizationUri, serverConfig.HomeRealmUri, serverConfig.Credentials, serverConfig.DeviceCredentials))
            {
                // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
                serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());

                using (var orgContext = new CrmServiceContext(serviceProxy))
                {
                    return orgContext.AccountSet.Where(item => item.Id == id).Select().Single();
                }
            }
```

there's also a good example in the SDK:

CRM2011Sdk\sdk\samplecode\cs\wsdlbasedproxies\online

Answer (score 3):

I use the "early bound" approach where you generate C# entity classes using the `CrmSvcUtil.exe` tool, but make sure you use the `/codecustomization` switch that you'll find in various examples. You'll need the latest version of the CRM 2011 SDK, and must run `CrmSvcUtil.exe` from the `\bin` folder of that (don't use the version that installs with CRM).

Your project will need to reference `Microsoft.Xrm.Client`, `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk` and `Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy` plus a few others from the .Net framework (look at the build errors to see what you're missing, then add them until it builds).

Here is a basic code snippet that retrieves a Contact entity, updates one of its fields, then saves it back to CRM:

```
CrmDataContext dc = new CrmDataContext("Xrm");

Contact contact = (from c in dc.ContactSet
                   where ...whatever...
                   select c).FirstOrDefault();

contact.FirstName = "Jo";

dc.SaveChanges();
```

(Note that `CrmDataContext` is the name of my data context. You can set this name using one of the `CrmSvcUtil` command line switches).

You'll also need to add a few things to your web.config:

```
<configSections>
   <section name="microsoft.xrm.client" type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Configuration.CrmSection, Microsoft.Xrm.Client" />
</configSections>

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Xrm" connectionString="Server=http://<your crm url>; Domain=<your domain>; Username=<a crm user id>; Password=<their password>" />
</connectionStrings>

<microsoft.xrm.client>
   <contexts>
      <add name="Xrm" type="" />
   </contexts>
</microsoft.xrm.client>
```

This is assuming you are running CRM on your corporate network, so the account and domain specified in the connection string would be an AD account, who is set up as a CRM user with relevant permissions to retrieve and update entities.